# How to know the PK to FK links in a middle table?

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, primary-key

I just started learning MySQL about a month ago. I would highly appreciate if someone could guide me on the 'join' table and does it always have to exist in a M to M relationship? Also, more importantly, how do I identify that it is a middle/join table? Are there alternatives to a join table? In my database below, I'm not sure if I'm doing my middle table's PK and FK linking right. I'm easily confused between the links between tables.

```
Drop Database if exists DBS;
Create database DBS;
use DBS;

create table Client(
client_id char(5) not null,
client_type varchar(30),
client_name varchar(50),
rep_firstname varchar(50),
rep_lastname varchar(50),
rep_phone varchar(30),
client_phone varchar(30),
client_address varchar(150),
client_state varchar(50),
primary key(client_id));

create table PhoneContact(
phone varchar(30) not null,
client_id char(5),
primary key (phone),
foreign key (client_id) references Client(client_id));

create table Staff(
staff_id char(5) not null,
staff_name varchar(20),
contract_details enum('full time, part time'),
phone varchar(20),
address varchar(150),
working_hours int(5),
pay_per_hour decimal(10,2) default null,
salary decimal(10,2) default 0,
primary key(staff_id));

create table Hostel(
hostel_id char(5) not null,
hostel_type enum('large dormitories', 'small shared rooms'),
price decimal(10,2),
max_guest int(3),
primary key(hostel_id));

create table Hotel(
hotel_id char(5) not null,
price decimal(10,2),
max_guest int(3),
primary key(hotel_id));

create table Camping(
camping_id char(5) not null,
price decimal(10,2),
max_guest int(3),
primary key(camping_id));

create table IndoorFacility(
indoor_id char(5) not null,
facility_type varchar(50),
start_time time,
checkout_time time,
booking_hours int(3),
charge_per_hour decimal(10,2),
primary key(indoor_id));

create table OutdoorFacility(
outdoor_id char(5) not null,
staff_id char(5),
booking_hours int(3),
outdoor_type varchar(50),
start_time time,
checkout_time time,
charge_per_hour decimal(10,2),
primary key(outdoor_id),
foreign key(staff_id) references Staff(staff_id));

create table Equipment(
equipment_id char(5) not null,
outdoor_id char(5),
equipment_name varchar(10),
price decimal(10,2),
booking_hours int(3),
primary key(equipment_id),
foreign key(outdoor_id) references OutdoorFacility(outdoor_id));

create table Payment(
payment_id char(5) not null,
client_id char(5),
payment_method enum('online','deposit'),
credit_card varchar(30),
created_at timestamp default current_timestamp,
primary key(payment_id),
foreign key(client_id) references Client(client_id));

create table AccommodationBooking(
accommodation_id char(5) not null,
hostel_id char(5),
hotel_id char(5),
camping_id char(5),
accommodation_type varchar(30),
booked_rooms int(3),
no_of_guests int(3),
primary key(accommodation_id),
foreign key(hostel_id) references Hostel(hostel_id),
foreign key(hotel_id) references Hotel(hotel_id),
foreign key(camping_id) references Camping(camping_id));

create table FacilityBooking(
facility_id char(5) not null,
indoor_id char(5),
outdoor_id char(5),
meal_type varchar(30),
created_at timestamp default current_timestamp,
primary key (facility_id),
foreign key(indoor_id) references IndoorFacility(indoor_id),
foreign key(outdoor_id) references OutdoorFacility(outdoor_id));

create table Booking(
booking_id char(5) not null,
client_id char(5),
accommodation_id char(5),
facility_id char(5),
checkin_date date,
checkout_date date,
created_at timestamp default current_timestamp,
primary key(booking_id),
foreign key (client_id) references Client(client_id),
foreign key (accommodation_id) references AccommodationBooking(accommodation_id),
foreign key (facility_id) references FacilityBooking(facility_id));
```

For example, from my database above, which are considered a middle table?

Comment: A join table is required for [fourth normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_normal_form) and is almost always present. Certain data warehousing applications may reduce normal form and have many-many join data *in situ*. As for knowing the linkages, usually a naming convention makes apparent the relationships: eg: `client_id` in all relevant tables, and a join named with relevant domains: `client_hostel`.

Comment: Middle table and join table aren't formal terms, while the meaning of relationship varies between ER, relational and network data models. ER and relational don't have the concept of links between tables. I suggest you study these disciplines to clarify the concepts. As it is your question isn't clear.

Comment: What reference(s) are you learning from? [Find an academic textbook/course](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24007275/3404097). Tables represent business relation(ship)s/associations--as in the RM (relational model) & the ERM (entity-relationhip model) or in "M:M relationship"). Many terms you are using are not the technical terms, and most of those technical terms come from presentations/methods/products/tools that misunderstand & misrepresent the RM. Your "links" are FKs (foreign keys) (ubiquitously mislabeled "relationships") & arise *after* designing as properties of a design.

Comment: A FK declaration just says subrow values somewhere must appear elsewhere. So declare every FK you can unless it's implied by others or it causes a cycle & your DBMS can't handle a cycle.

Comment: @bishop Your 1st sentence is unintelligible. Your 2nd sentence is not clear; it can be interpreted as making sense, but only by someone who already knows enough about the terms you're using. Re your 3rd sentence, guessing is no way to build things.

Comment: Using multiple FKs of which one is non-null is an anti-pattern. Google SO re database/sql subtypes/polymorphism, also re 2/many/multiple FKs to 2/many/multiple tables.